# Yet another query mobile file upload issue

Tags: php, forms, email, jquery-mobile, attachment

First of all, I've seen so many suggestions on similar issues, however, I haven't found any that fit exactly what I'm trying to do.

I have a form that posts to a PHP email submission, and at the end of the form I would like the user to have the option to attach multiple photos from either the camera app, or gallery (I've read that iPhones don't allow access to the camera app, but Androids do) and send it all in a nice little email. I keep getting an undefined index error on all of my attachment lines. Now, I've exhausted my copy-fu troubleshooting, and have now resorted to asking people who actually know a lot more about PHP syntax than I do. Here's the end of my form where the attachment section is (the whole page is pretty extensive and elaborate, and I can display if needed, but this is the only part that's giving me headaches...):

```
<form data-ajax="false" method="post" action="mo-mail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

(all of the other options, and then...)

```
<label for="attachments">Upload Photos:</label>
            <input type="file" name="attachment1" id="attachment1" class="ui-input-text" />
            <input type="file" name="attachment2" id="attachment2" class="ui-input-text" />
            <input type="file" name="attachment3" id="attachment3" class="ui-input-text" />
            <input type="file" name="attachment4" id="attachment4" class="ui-input-text" />
            <input type="file" name="attachment5" id="attachment5" class="ui-input-text" />
            <p>*Please only press the Submit button once. Large sized photos require longer time to upload</p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Request" data-disabled="false">
```

Then there's my PHP page in it's entirety:

```
<?php

$MOfirstname = $_POST['MOfirstname'];
$MOlastname = $_POST['MOlastname'];
$MOcompany = $_POST['MOcompany'];
$MOemail = $_POST['MOemail'];
$MOphone = $_POST['MOphone'];
$MOmodelnumber = $_POST['MOmodelnumber'];
$MOvoltage = $_POST['MOvoltage'];
$MOoperation = $_POST['MOoperation'];
$MOfused = $_POST['MOfused'];
$MOtriptype = $_POST['MOtriptype'];
$MOfusesize = $_POST['MOfusesize'];
$MOquantity = $_POST['MOquantity'];
$MOcomments = $_POST['MOcomments'];
$MOdelivery = $_POST['MOdelivery'];
$MOmailinglist = $_POST['MOmailinglist'];
$MO_Function = implode(", ", $_POST['MO_Function']);
$MOquote = implode(", ", $_POST['MOquote']);
$MOAux = implode(", ", $_POST['MOAux']);
$MOAuxSwitchSize = $_POST['MOAuxSwitchSize'];
$MOAuxShuntTripVoltage = $_POST['MOAuxShuntTripVoltage'];
$MOBellAlarm_OTS_Voltage = $_POST['MOBellAlarm_OTS_Voltage'];
$MOBellAlarm_OTS_Operation = $_POST['MOBellAlarm_OTS_Operation'];

$attachment1 = $field_file = $_POST['attachment1'];
$tmpName1 = $_FILES['attachment1']['tmp_name1'];
$fileType1 = $_FILES['attachment1']['type1'];
$fileName1 = $_FILES['attachment1']['name1'];
$attachment2 = $field_file = $_POST['attachment2'];
$tmpName2 = $_FILES['attachment2']['tmp_name2'];
$fileType2 = $_FILES['attachment2']['type2'];
$fileName2 = $_FILES['attachment2']['name2'];
$attachment3 = $field_file = $_POST['attachment3'];
$tmpName3 = $_FILES['attachment3']['tmp_name3'];
$fileType3 = $_FILES['attachment3']['type3'];
$fileName3 = $_FILES['attachment3']['name3'];
$attachment4 = $field_file = $_POST['attachment4'];
$tmpName4 = $_FILES['attachment4']['tmp_name4'];
$fileType4 = $_FILES['attachment4']['type4'];
$fileName4 = $_FILES['attachment4']['name4'];
$attachment5 = $field_file = $_POST['attachment5'];
$tmpName5 = $_FILES['attachment5']['tmp_name5'];
$fileType5 = $_FILES['attachment5']['type5'];
$fileName5 = $_FILES['attachment5']['name5'];

if(empty($MOfirstname)||empty($MOemail)||empty($MOlastname)||empty($MOcompany)||empty($MOphone)) 
{
    echo "<div style ='font:36px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;color:#ff0000'>Please click the Back button and fill in all contact information.</div>";
    exit;
}

$to = "myemail@privacy.com";
$email_from = 'myemail@privacy.com';
$email_subject = "New Mobile Submission";
$email_body = "You have received a new query from $MOfirstname $MOlastname at $MOcompany about a $MOmodelnumber. They can be reached at $MOphone or $MOemail.\n".

    "Here is the request:\n \n
    Quantity: $MOquantity
    Model: $MOmodelnumber
    Frame Size: $MOvoltage
    Operation: $MOoperation
    Fused: $MOfused
    Fuse Size: $MOfusesize
    Trip Type: $MOtriptype
    Functions: $MO_Function
    Auxillary Devices: $MOAux
        Auxillary Switch Size: $MOAuxSwitchSize
        Auxillary Shunt Trip Voltage: $MOAuxShuntTripVoltage
        Bell Alarm/OTS Operation = $MOBellAlarm_OTS_Operation
        Bell Alarm/OTS Voltage: $MOBellAlarm_OTS_Voltage
    Additional Info: $MOcomments
    Mailing List: $MOmailinglist


    They would like a quote for the following:
        $MOquote

    With a desired delivery of:
        $MOdelivery";


$headers = "From:myemail@privacy.com \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $MOemail \r\n"; 
    {
          /* Reading file ('rb' = read binary)  */
          $file1 = fopen($tmpName1,'rb');
          $data1 = fread($file1,filesize($tmpName1));
          fclose($file1);

          $file2 = fopen($tmpName2,'rb');
          $data2 = fread($file2,filesize($tmpName2));
          fclose($file2);

          $file3 = fopen($tmpName3,'rb');
          $data3 = fread($file3,filesize($tmpName3));
          fclose($file3);

          $file4 = fopen($tmpName4,'rb');
          $data4 = fread($file4,filesize($tmpName4));
          fclose($file4);

          $file5 = fopen($tmpName5,'rb');
          $data5 = fread($file5,filesize($tmpName5));
          fclose($file5);

            /* a boundary string */
          $randomVal = md5(time());
          $mimeBoundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$randomVal}x";

          /* Header for File Attachment */
          $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n";
          $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" ;
          $headers .= " boundary=\"{$mimeBoundary}\"";

          /* Multipart Boundary above message */
          $email_body = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
          "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" .
          "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
          "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
          $email_body . "\n\n";

          /* Encoding file data */
          $data1 = chunk_split(base64_encode($data1));
          $data2 = chunk_split(base64_encode($data2));
          $data3 = chunk_split(base64_encode($data3));
          $data4 = chunk_split(base64_encode($data4));
          $data5 = chunk_split(base64_encode($data5));

          /* Adding attchment-file to message*/
          $email_body .= "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" .
          "Content-Type: {$fileType};\n" .
          " name=\"{$fileName1}\"\n" .
          "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
          $data1 . "\n\n" .
          "--{$mimeBoundary}--\n";

          $email_body .= "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" .
          "Content-Type: {$fileType};\n" .
          " name=\"{$fileName2}\"\n" .
          "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
          $data2 . "\n\n" .
          "--{$mimeBoundary}--\n";

          $email_body .= "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" .
          "Content-Type: {$fileType};\n" .
          " name=\"{$fileName3}\"\n" .
          "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
          $data3 . "\n\n" .
          "--{$mimeBoundary}--\n";

          $email_body .= "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" .
          "Content-Type: {$fileType};\n" .
          " name=\"{$fileName4}\"\n" .
          "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
          $data4 . "\n\n" .
          "--{$mimeBoundary}--\n";

          $email_body .= "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" .
          "Content-Type: {$fileType};\n" .
          " name=\"{$fileName5}\"\n" .
          "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
          $data5 . "\n\n" .
          "--{$mimeBoundary}--\n";
    }
function IsInjected($str)
{
    $injections = array('(\n+)',
           '(\r+)',
           '(\t+)',
           '(%0A+)',
           '(%0D+)',
           '(%08+)',
           '(%09+)'
           );

    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";

    if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
}

if(IsInjected($MOemail))
{
    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit;
}
@mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
header("Location: thank-you.html");

?>
```

Ok...ultimately, I'd like the attachments to be added as attachments to the email, but I don't want the user to HAVE to attach all 5 photos...

...and I'm sure there's a much simpler way to accomplish this than the way I approached it, but I'm open to suggestions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I guess the lack of response was a sign that how I was approaching this was way over complicated, and/or made no sense...thus, nobody wanted to touch it.

I was able to get it to work with PHPMailer.